# WPF Loading spinner with customized gif

Tags: wpf, spinner

I want to show a customized gif image as a loading spinner indicator for a long processing task in WPF.
How can I achieve the same?

Comment: Read [this post](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: One way would be to google something like: wpf custom image indicator which would lead you to a post like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712787/is-it-possible-to-change-the-busy-animation-in-the-busyindicator-of-extended-wpf

Comment: I cannot use any 3rd party or extended toolkit. Can this be achieved via creation of a user control in wpf itself.

Comment: Does this help at all? http://stackoverflow.com/q/19694640/1001985

Comment: What about this solution here 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71891/WPF-GIF-Animation